# Can I plot complex function and how?

Tags: complex-numbers, graphing-functions

pleas help me i need to plot sin(z) in Graphing Calculator 3D.
Iam sorey for my bad english
can i wrote 
w=sin(z) ?
and get nothing

Comment: http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Sin/visualizations/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that, since the graph of $\sin$ is a subset of $\mathbb C^2=\mathbb R^4$.

But you use the fact that$$\sin(x+yi)=\sin(x)\cosh(y)+\cos(x)\sinh(y)i.$$The, you can graph:

- the real part of $\sin(z)$, which is $\sin(x)\cosh(y)$;
- the imaginary part of $\sin(z)$, which is $\cos(x)\sinh(y)$;
- the absolute value of $\sin(z)$, which is $\sqrt{\bigl(\sin(x)\cosh(y)\bigr)^2+\bigl(\cos(x)\sinh(y)\bigr)^2}$.

Comment: i think these solve my problem but "i" in the imaginary part changes my function to the red color.

Comment: There is no $i$ in the imaginary part. The imaginary part of $a+bi$ is $b$, not $bi$.